# How to block access to a folder and all its content if it is accessed outside localhost?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make admin folder accessible just to users reaching site from localhost.

The configuration that calls PHP-FPM is below. Let's call it main snippet.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

If I use the following snippet after the main snippet (let's call it blocking snippet)

```
location ~ /(admin) {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny  all;
}
```

users that access /admin folder from 127.0.0.1. Users that access it from its public IP (say 192.168.0.71)
have access denied. Great (but not that much).
If they try to access any PHP file inside /admin folder, PHP code is executed but no other asset is accessed (for instance, /admin/index.php)

Then I moved the blocking snippet so it would sit above the main snippet.

In this case, if someone tries to access /admin folder or any content (even PHP code), he/she gets the error 403 (access denied).
Great (but again, not that much).

If someone tries to access /admin folder from 127.0.0.1 access is granted but PHP code is not executed as it is handled by main snippet that is below the blocking snippet. Instead of get executed, the PHP code is downloaded.

Then I thought to use the following snippet

```
location ~ /(admin.*\.php) {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny  all;
}
```

below the main snippet. But it didn't worked either (probably because main snippet got executed)

So my question:
How can I allow users to access /admin folder from IP 127.0.0.1 and deny access to it and all its content (including PHP execution) if accessed from another IP?

What is wrong in my approach? I googled but I failed to find a solution.

**Edit:** configuration after Gary suggestion

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
}

location ~ /(admin\/?) {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny  all;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add the entire 'main' snippet within the 'blocking' snippet and move it above the original 'main' snippet.

Basically, you've got two totally different locations as far as nginx is concerned, so you get no PHP processing unless you ask for it in the 'blocking' snippet.

Comment: I edited my question with resulting configuration after trying to implement your suggestion (I'm not sure I understood it very well - my bad Engilsh is the reason).
It is working almost perfect. The only problem is that now from IP 127.0.0.1 I'm able to access just /admin folder. If I try to access any other part of the site its content is download (eg.: index.php is downloaded when acessing http://127.0.0.1/).